# Matching the cell size of two tables

Tags: html, css

Basically, because of the layout of my website ( I'm using IP.Content with my IP.Board forum ) I can't really have a single table here. Well, I probably could, but I don't understand how, so I might be asking the wrong question.

Anyway, here's my code:

```
<div class="box" style="width: 81%; float: right;">
    <div class="ipsSideBlock clearfix __xXtop20520players">
        <h3 id="anonymous_element_8">
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <th style='text-align: center;'> Icon </th>
                    <th style='text-align: center;'> Item Name </th>
                    <th style='text-align: center;'> Description </th>
                    <th style='text-align: center;'> Price </th>
                    <th style='text-align: center;'> Controls </th>
                </tr>
            </h3>
        </table>
        <div class="_sbcollapsable">
            <ul class="shoplist">
                <li class="clearfix">
                    <div class="list_content">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50.png" width="50px" height="50px"/> </td>
                                <td> Item </td>
                                <td> This is a test description </td>
                                <td> $29.99 </td>
                                <td> Button. </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have the Table header and the Table data in different sections, this is because of the sheer amount of styling that comes with IP.Board. I'm not very experienced with any of this, but this looks exactly how I want it to.

The only problem is that the table data doesn't stretch the table-headers sizes accordingly with the data. When I look at it, it makes sense as to why. I attempted to leave the table open, but that just made everything show up in the h3 element.

Comment: What a mess! Why won't you just use one table? Also, you have `<h3><table></h3></table>` - which is easy to see because the code is actually formatted very well.

Comment: Can you change the DOM or not?

Comment: @Kobi - This doesn't work, it unfortunately stores everything inside of the <h3> even if I break the table after it.

Comment: Is it generated by a server- or client-side script or written by hand or is it a template? I don't see what's the point in two tables. If you have to collapse the rows (I guess by class "_sbcollapsable") you can easily do it by hiding the tr-s in the table. Then it's better to move the <th>s into a <thead> instead of a <tr>. So it's really easy to hide the rows (collapse the table).

Comment: @Kobi: `<h3><table></h3></table>` is against html code validity.

Comment: @Václav - Right! But that's from the question...

Comment: @Christian.tucker: If I understood what you need, I think that question should be: **How to use one table in IP.Content** instead **How to match cell size of two tables**.

Comment: @Václav - My question is more of how to match a tables size across multiple divs, then it is how to use it with a specific product.